# Расстановка запятых в обороте "от и до" с уточнением

Tags: пунктуация

> Движения варьируются от простых – в направлении влево и вправо до более сложных, которые включают вращение и масштабирование.

Как расставить запятые правильно?

Answer (score 2):

*Движения варьируются от простых, **в направлении влево и вправо**, до более сложных, которые включают вращение и масштабирование.*

В данном случае удобнее использовать обособление запятой, так как союз И связывает обстоятельства   в единую конструкцию. Для обособления более сложных выражений, где есть собственные знаки,  нужно использовать два тире (по правилу обособления вставных конструкций).

Answer (score 0):

*Движения варьируются от простых, в направлении влево и вправо, — до более сложных.*

Обособленное уточнение принадлежит первой части оборота *от... до*, т. е. «о простых движениях». И без тире отчётливо передать это противопоставление (простого и сложного) не получится.

Можно заменить союз *и*, и коль скоро идёт речь о движении, связать два слова более динамичным элементом:

*Движения варьируются от простых, в направлении влево-вправо, — до более сложных.*